# i have upgraded flutter 1.22.6 to flutter 2.0.1.. but now dependency packages are throwing error

Tags: flutter, dependencies, upgrade

Because google_api_headers <0.2.0-nullsafety.0 depends on package_info >=0.4.0 <2.0.0 and google_api_headers >=0.2.0-nullsafety.0 <1.0.0 depends on package_info ^0.5.0-nullsafety, google_api_headers <1.0.0 requires package_info >=0.4.0 <2.0.0.
And because flutter_google_places >=0.2.7 depends on google_api_headers >=0.1.0 <1.0.0 and google_map_location_picker 4.1.7 depends on package_info ^2.0.0, flutter_google_places >=0.2.7 is incompatible with google_map_location_picker 4.1.7.
Because google_map_location_picker >=4.1.3 <4.1.7 depends on provider ^4.3.3 and no versions of google_map_location_picker match >4.1.7 <5.0.0, google_map_location_picker >=4.1.3 <4.1.7-∞ or >4.1.7 <5.0.0 requires provider ^4.3.3.
Thus, if flutter_google_places >=0.2.7 and google_map_location_picker ^4.1.3 then provider ^4.3.3.
And because project depends on google_map_location_picker ^4.1.3, flutter_google_places >=0.2.7 requires provider ^4.3.3.
So, because project depends on both flutter_google_places ^0.2.8 and provider ^5.0.0, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in wh-driver...
pub get failed (1; So, because project depends on both flutter_google_places ^0.2.8 and provider ^5.0.0, version solving failed.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a versioning error, and a solution for it is in the official docs only, read about it [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#conflict-resolution).

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY SOLUTION IS TO MATCH THE DEPENDENCIES WHICH SUPPORT EACH OTHER AND TO OVERRIDE THE DEPENDENCIES WHICH ARE NOT SATISFIED WITH THIS MATCHING